# Is malloc() executed differently according to single or multiple thread?

Tags: linux, malloc, glibc

In glibc, mutex for arena's synchronization seems to be executed differently according to single or multiple thread. Is there anybody who knows about synchronization method in glibc's malloc?

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: If you don't have multiple threads, it doesn't need a mutex.

Comment: I made a new malloc library for my project based on the original glibc's malloc. And It doesn't work well in multiple thread circumstance with my malloc mechanism. But, as far as i studied the problem, it is for mutex used for arena's synchronization. So, now I'm wondering whether or not there are different mutex interfaces according to single or multiple threads in malloc mechanism of glibc.

Answer (score 0):

Not for the faint-hearted, but [glibc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=malloc;h=e792885d1ff8316c82309c1136605f63490724f0;hb=a7d1c51482d15ab6c07e2ee0ae5e007067b18bfb) puts in a lot of effort to ensure that thread contention issues are kept to a minimum. There are more sophisticated allocators available for very specific patterns of use, like [Horde](http://www.hoard.org/). Other interesting resources, might include the very clean, [musl (libc)](http://www.musl-libc.org/).